# Get array of strings from Facter into Puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

In a module I'm working on, I need to check if specific users exist on a machine.
The idea was to create a custom fact that contains an array of all users.
In the module, it should iterate through the array and check if a specific user is part of the array.

My Custom Fact:

```
Facter.add("users") do
  setcode do
    IO.readlines("/etc/passwd").collect do |line|
      line.split(":").first
    end
  end
end
```

The output of the fact is a String like this:
["user1", "user2", "user3"]

Because it is just a string and no array, I'm unable to iterate through it in my puppet module.

I then tried

```
  shell_split($::users).each |String $user| {
    notify { "$user":}
  }
```

But now, each user contains a comma after the username.

Do you have an idea for a working and better solution?

Comment: _"The output of the fact is a String like this: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']"_ - It does not look like a string. It is an array.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yeah it looks like an array. But the point is, that it is a string with the content of an array.
If I use validate_array(), It also tells me that it's not an array but a string.

Comment: You will need to elaborate "string with content of an array". Can you paste what you actually have in your terminal?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. That fact code outputs an array for me and not a string. I double checked it with `.instance_of?(Array)` to verify. You will need to post more information to verify that your question matches your situation.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Yeah inside of the ruby code/fact, it is an array. But the fact doesn't pass it as array to puppet (but as a string).
validate_array($::users) tells me 
"[\"user1\", \"user2\", \"user3\"]" is not an Array.  It looks to be a String

Comment: This is pretty much a textbook example of a method that does too much that should be broken up so that you can test and understand the components better individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The output of the fact is a String like this: ["user1", "user2", "user3"]

No, it isn't.  The Ruby code you presented in the fact's `setcode` block evaluates to an array.  That expression provides the value of the fact.  It is an array.

It is possible, however, that Puppet *converts* that array to a string after receiving it from Facter.  Puppet 3 did this by default, but had a boolean `stringify_facts` configuration setting that could prevent that behavior.  Puppet 4 retained that setting but deprecated it and reversed its default value (to `false`).  Puppet 5 removed the setting, and never stringifies fact values.

Therefore, if you are using (obsolete) Puppet 3 then you can avoid fact stringification by setting

```
stringify_facts = false
```

in the `[main]` section of your `puppet.conf` files on the master and all agents.  You can do the same on Puppet 4, but there you can also just ensure that the `stringify_facts` setting is not  explicitly set at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have this as the output of `Factor.add`:

```
output = '["user1", "user2", "user3"]'
```

You can convert it to an `Array` with the help of [`JSON`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse output
 => ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

Comment: Sorry for my wrong output. It is already like
["user1", "user2", "user3"] 
but the output is just a string with the content of above.
I can only pass a string from facter to puppet.
Inside the fact, it is an array I guess.